# Advanced Pricing Import Export issue

Tags: magento2, import, export, importexport, advanced-pricing

I am having an issue with the Advanced Pricing import.
I am importing a new pricing file and I selected Replace as the action, but it is not replacing the file.  There are 9,219 line items in the file that I am importing and when I finish the import and export the file there are 9,434 line items in the file. If I export again it will give the different number of record every time. i.e. Import one time and every time export will give the different number of product with advance price in csv.

Comment: I guess that  you have some meoty row at end of  csv

Comment: Also save the csv  at utf-8 format upload it

Comment: @AmitBera , When export advance price CSV file , everytime we it gives different number of rows in the CSV file.

Comment: Is there any solution? Why i am everytime got the different number of rows in the CSV file?